# I have been deploying on vercel but getting cors error even though I am setting the headers

Tags: node.js, reactjs, vite, vercel

I have been using react + nodejs
Although I have set the `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"` header still I am getting the corss error.
PS - `virmigo.vercel.app` is my frontend url

[image]

NodeJs

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://virmigo.vercel.app");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version"
  );
  next();
});
```

vercel.json

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "name": "virmigo",
  "builds": [{ "src": "app.js", "use": "@vercel/node" }],

  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "./app.js",
      "methods": ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"],
      "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://virmigo.vercel.app",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because of your `https://virmigo-backend.vercel.app` url (**backend**) are not allowed cors policy. You are getting a cors error when you hit the **front-end** url `https://virmigo.vercel.app`.
But this error generates from your **back-end url**. In your case, your backend url seems to be `https://virmigo.vercel.app`.

To Fix this issue, you must solve it on your backend server. By simply taking a few steps, you can do that.

Install the CORS package on your backend server.

```
npm i cors
```

Then import CORS

```
import cors from 'cors';
```

And the last step is to use cors configuration on your application.

```
const app = express();

const options = [
  cors({
    origin: '*',
    methods: '*',
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
    credentials: true,
  })
];

app.use(options);
```

**Note**: For better security you can only use your front-end url `origin: 'https://virmigo-backend.vercel.app'`, except of using `origin: '*'`.

Comment: I am already using cors package.

`app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "https://virmigo.vercel.app",
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PATCH", "DELETE"],
    credentials: true,
  })
);`

Comment: Try to use this:-

`cors({
    origin: '*',
    methods: '*',
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
    credentials: true,
  })`

Comment: I ran my server locally it worked correctly I think it is vercel's problem.